# How to Dynamically Render a javascript file for Users with different level of roles in Asp .Net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Recently I got into Trouble with JavaScript in ASP.Net MVC5
 My Issue like this I want to Render a script with functions and templates of html for users using same page(say Index.cshtml )
 It should be dynamically rendered based on user account in identity system.

I tried string type of JavaScript code as profile information for user and render it using script tag in user view. The Controller with return type of JavaScript.
It Works But I need a Better Implementation of it.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Atom(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string userScript = string.Empty; ;
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

            //Read the contents of CSV file.
            userScript = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        }

        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        user.cscript = userScript;

        UserManager.Update(user);

        return RedirectToAction("Cscript");
    }
```

And here is my Controller for Js result

```
    public JavaScriptResult js(string email)
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(email);

        return JavaScript(user.cscript);
    }
```

Comment: You could have different static JavaScript files/bundles which get conditionally rendered to the layout depending on user/role/etc.

Comment: But I dont have to Configure the bundle.config file everytime a new newuser is logged is signed up

Comment: One would certainly hope not.  Are you specifically tailoring your code to *each user*?  That seems like it's going to become a maintenance nightmare very quickly, regardless of how you deliver that code.  Normally one would have specific logic based on some finite and unchanging grouping of users, such as by role.

Comment: That is a  user feature to write their own JavaScript for their pages i just simply render it using script tag.

Comment: Then can't you just output the value to the page like you would *any other value* from the database?  What exactly is the problem?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: it not from the database it is from rest endpoint the result from the endpoint is dynamic i can only iterate the key and value over a table.

Comment: The problem is every user wants the result to be on their own fashion in the table. For example user A wants the column to be alphabetically ordered. and user B wants to different. So i cannot iterate the table columns and rows. Instead I Fetch a Template from the user code and rendered it using the javascript.

Comment: How did iterating a table suddenly become part of this?  It’s become completely unclear what you’re asking at this point.  But if you have some user-specific values that you want to output to the page, regardless of where you get those values, then just output them to the page.  Have you actually tried anything?  What isn’t working?

Comment: The whole idea is this:

Comment: Whole scenario is like this:
1. User goes to a page where he can code or upload a js file.
2.Then the user goes to another page to see his code rendered in that page
3.So I am doing this by 
First i fetch the code from the editor and save it in my local system with reference to the user.
Then i Simply read it inside my controller and return a JavaScript result to user to their output page.

my Question is Is there any alternate way to achieve the scenario.